# Should we retain posts that are not answers?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Recently there has been a post that has been recommended for deletion by 6 reviewers out of 6.

The thing is that while being reviewed, it accumulated a few upvotes, meaning that the system has ignored the deletion recommendations.

I raised a moderator flag explaining the situation, but while it has been deemed useful, the post is still there, despite being little more than a comment.

I am not posting a link to the post in question because I would like to have a discussion as general as possible without pointing fingers at anyone, I understand that everyone has different moderation philosophies.

**As a community, what do we want to do with posts that gather 6 deletion recommendations and have a positive score?**

Please bear in mind that outsiders coming through the HQN can easily upvote, but are not necessarily familiar with our community, meaning that a positive score is not necessarily indicative of a good answer.

Comment: I haven't researched the general SE functionality, but what are the options? AFAIK the mechanisms for voting, flagging etc. are common to all SE sites so I'm not sure what we could do differently. Are you asking if we should bypass those mechanisms by 'requiring' moderators to delete posts that have been recommended for deletion even if they have upvotes? And I suppose that any 'solution' here assumes that we can all agree to ignore/override upvotes in certain cases. At first glance, that seems like it might be very subjective and tricky to handle consistently.

Comment: @Pondlife if it is too broad I can accept it as an answer, given that a workable "case by case" solution is suggested (chatroom open to discuss these occurrences?). And yes, the question is if we, as a community, want to ask the mods to enforce those recommendations. Feel free to edit the post if you feel it can be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would say that unless there are clear indications that someone explicitly disagrees, the post should be nuked.

Would qualify as "clear indications" comments arguing that it is a good post, or votes not to delete/"looks ok". I would not consider upvotes for the reason stated in the question: the post might have gotten in the HNQ list and have received upvotes from people not familiar with the community.

If instead there are clear indications that the post is considered a good one, a first tentative to clear up the dispute can be done in the main chatroom, followed by a dedicated meta question if the issue is not resolved in chat (e.g.: the people involved do not participate in chat).